# How to add link buttons with label in quickly glade

Tags: 14.04, gnome, quickly, development, button

I'm making my own application, I can add link buttons on quickly glade, but the link buttons dont have a label, they just have "button" written on them. How can I add my own label on the link buttons? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also can't find an option in Glade 3.16 which is shipped with Ubuntu 14.04. They made some major GUI changes, so it's possible they forgot about this property. You could check if there's a bug report about it.

In the meantime set the label property in your Python code:

```
linkbutton.set_label("My Website")
```